# Is "write the materials are belong" correct? Or is it "The materials belong"?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct? Is it

> "The materials are belong" 
>   or 
>   "The materials belong?"

Comment: ["All your base are belong to us"](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us)

Answer (score 1):

As stated on [Merriam Webster,](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/belong)
***belong*** is a transitive verb. Never can ***belong*** be used as an adjective.

> The materials belong here.

is correct.

> The materials are belong here.

is incorrect (in grammar *and* speech).
If belong is the adjective, which the above example implies, then what part of speech is *here*?

Answer (score -1):

'The materials belong ' is correct. 'The materials are belong ' is completely wrong.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: @skooba I apologize, I'm new

Comment: We all were at one time. The above response came from the "First Post" review queue. Think of it as a helpful hint or constructive criticism.

Comment: @skooba of course

Comment: If you want to avoid your answer being deleted, try editing the post to provide more information. Why is one correct and one incorrect? Can you support those claims with links? You may benefit from reading [how to ask a question](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @hank Sure, of course